# Как сделать, чтобы при смене радиокнопки удалялось прибавленное значение и прибавлялось новое?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например, если нажимаю +10, то к 100 прибавляется 10. Надо чтобы при мене на +20 или +30, удалялось прибавленное +10 и добавлялось новое.

```js
$('.rbuttons').on('change', function () {
  let first = Number($('.total').html());
  let plus = Number($('.rbuttons input:checked').attr("data"));
  let total = (first + plus);
  $('.total').text(total);
});
$('.box label').on('change', function () {
    if( $('.checkbox input').is(':checked') ) {
        let current = Number( $('.total').html() );
        let plus = Number( $(this).find('input').attr("data") );
        let total = (current + plus);
        $('.total').html(total);
    } else {
        let current = Number( $('.total').html() );
        let plus = Number( $(this).find('input').attr("data") );
        let total = (current - plus);
        $('.total').html(total);
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.box {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
span {
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.first,
.total {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>+10
        <input type="checkbox" data="10">
      <label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>+40
        <input type="checkbox" data="40">
      <label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>+30
        <input type="checkbox" data="30">
      <label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rbuttons">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>+10
        <input name="plus" type="radio" data="10">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>+20
        <input name="plus" type="radio" data="20">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>+30
        <input name="plus" type="radio" data="30">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>=</span>
  <div class="total">100</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проще всего - хранить в переменной основное значение (100) и при изменении складывать эта переменная + data-атрибут (так-то зачем он? можно же value использовать)

Comment: А если так (дополнил разметку), с чекбоксами?

Comment: Ответ прежний. Данные изменения ничего не меняют. Суть в том что у вас есть переменная (константа с изначальным значением - 100) которая не меняется и вы собираете все данные с эл-тов + эта переменная

Comment: Если взять 100 за константу, а потом чекбоксом к ней прибавить 10 и записать в .total 100+10 (110), то потом при прибавлении радиокнопкой будет снова 100+10 и 110 (полученное из константы + data чекбокса) будет переписано на 110. А должно получиться 120.

Comment: сделайте функцию, которая при onchange будет считать чекнутые инпуты и плюсовать к ним 100, затем перезаписывать в total. И не надо ничего удалять, просто будет писаться общая сумма.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('input').on('change', function () { 
  total()
})

function total(){
  let chk = 0
  $('input:checked').each(function () { 
    chk += +$(this).attr('data')
  })
  let total = 100+chk
  $('.total').text(total)
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.box {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
span {
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.first,
.total {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>+10
        <input type="checkbox" data="10">
      <label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>+40
        <input type="checkbox" data="40">
      <label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>+30
        <input type="checkbox" data="30">
      <label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rbuttons">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>+10
        <input name="plus" type="radio" data="10">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>+20
        <input name="plus" type="radio" data="20">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>+30
        <input name="plus" type="radio" data="30">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>=</span>
  <div class="total">100</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: В данном случае особо не влияет, но лучше брать только checked эл-ты `$('input:checked')`, тогда и условий никаких не нужно, и выборка меньше.

Comment: @InDevX да, поправил

Comment: А в идеале, ещё chk лишняя, можно сразу тотал = 100 и плюсовать; ну и функцию передавать вместо вызова `$('input').on('change', total)`